# Package development: run_examples could not find function

Tags: r, devtools

I'm developing an R package, `pk`, say.  I've successfully installed it and used it, and now I'm trying to clean up the examples with the help of the `run_examples` function in the `devtools` package.  However, it crashes on the very first example:

```
> require(pk)
> require(devtools)
> run_examples("~/[full path]/pk")
Updating pk documentation
Running 45 example files in pk
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading pk
Running examples in pk-package.Rd
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1> ########################################################################
1> ## Simulate a dataset ... blah blah
1> set.seed(1)
1> x = my_pk_fun(a = 1)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "my_pk_fun"
Loading pk
```

As I already loaded my package (using `require`), what more do I have to do to make `my_pk_fun` visible to `run_examples`?  I've checked that `my_pk_fun` is indeed present in my R session.

**UPDATE:**
Following the comment by Dirk, I examined my namespace file, and found it to be completely empty.  As suggested (though not recommended) by the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces), I inserted `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")`, which, it seems, is supposed to export all of the functions, including `my_pk_fun`.  However, upon repeating the experiment above, (a) I get the same error, and (b) the contents of the namespace file are deleted!  Why does `run_examples` empty my namespace file?

Comment: Did you export `my_pk_fun` via the `NAMESPACE` file?

Answer (score 0):

I conjecture a resolution of my own question:

One detail that I omitted is that before I could get `run_examples` to do anything at all, it required me to first install the `roxygen2` package (even though `roxygen2` is listed only under "suggests" in the `devtools` documentation!).

When digging through the source code of `run_examples`, I did indeed find some use of `roxygenize`.  It has been [previously noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597993/does-roxygen2-automatically-write-namespace-directives-for-imports-packages) that roxygenizing a package can have the effect of rewriting the `NAMESPACE` file.

To be explicit, the reason that `run_examples` empties my `NAMESPACE` file is that (1) `run_examples` roxygenized my package while (2) I never included any `# @export` command (or any other roxygen2-speak, for that matter) in my source files.

Conclusion:  Unless you are building your package within the `roxygen2` framework, and including all of your `.Rd` documentation as comments in your source code, then do not use `run_examples`!  It seems like there should be a warning about this in the `run_examples` documentation.

**A way out:**  If you really must use `run_examples`, and you're willing to learn a little bit about `roxygen`, which is actually pretty cool, then start [here](http://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/Rd2roxygen/index.html).