# Make third party library available in my R package

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2

I am developing an R package that uses third party functions
available in the Bioconductor package "methyilumi"

In the code for my R package at the very beginning I import methylumi
with `library(methylumi)`.

During the development (I use roxygen2 and devtools) everything works fine.
However, when I install the package and run my functions, I get the error:
`could not find function "methylumIDAT"`.

Of course everything is solved if I import the package manually, but how can I make
so that `methylumi` is available whenever I load my own package?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the code for my package ... library(methylumi)" ?  Do you have the proper imports in your `NAMESPACE` file?  Have you read the  `R-exts` tutorial file?

Comment: Hi Carl, I did read the R-exts tutorial, but I have to admit not everything is crystal clear to me.

Say I have my main file "mypackage.r" in the R folder, what I did is adding library(methylumi) at the top of the file.
I generate NAMESPACE using roxygen2 (but there are no lines for methyulimi), also in my DESCRIPTION file I have added a Depends statement for methylumi.

Comment: I'm no expert in `NAMESPACE` either, but have a look at the files for the package `Rmpfr` for some example code. HTH :-)

Comment: You need to add an @import directive in "mypackage.R" (you don't need `library`).  `roxygen2` will set up the NAMESPACE for you.  You will still need to add the import entry in DESCRIPTION.  See this **[SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597993/does-roxygen2-automatically-write-namespace-directives-for-imports-packages)**.  Also, consider using import over depends, as import only makes the package available within your package as per this **[other SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637993/better-explanation-of-when-to-use-imports-depends)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using devtools, you can add

```
devtools::use_package("methyilumi")
```

in the console, and call `methyilumi::methylumIDAT` in the body of your function. That way, the package is automatically listed in `Imports` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

This sections gives the instructions for several different cases:
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports

Answer (score 2):

This is done with the NAMESPACE file and also noted in the DESCRIPTION file. There are a few ways to import a function in NAMESPACE, but the simplest is just `importFrom("[PACKAGE_NAME]",[FUNCTION_NAME)`. Then, in DESCRIPTION, add the package name to imports.

See this very good tutorial from Friedrich Leisch.

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf