# Writing an R package: needing a package I don't explicitly call

Tags: r

I'm working on an R package that uses the `spTransform` function in the `sp` package. The rub is that this function need `rgdal` loaded to work, or I get an error message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : load package rgdal for spTransform methods
```

My `Imports` statement in the `DESCRIPTION` file includes the following:

```
Imports: sp,
    rgdal
```

But I'm still getting the error. *However*, if I explcitly load rgdal (using `library(rgdal)`) before using the package, everything works fine. I'm guessing that when my package is loaded rgdal is not attached because none of my code uses it explcitly via `::` etc.

So I think my question is: How can I make my package attach a package that I am not explicitly using?

Comment: This has come up in the r-dev mailing list. I think you need to also use the correct specifications in your NAMESPACE file.

Comment: Can you show what your NAMESPACE file looks like?

Comment: It should probably be included in Imports if the package won't work without it and needs to use the namespace.  I'm hesitant to say Depends but possibly that too/instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said by **BondedDust**, you need to import the required packages into your package NAMESPACE. To do so edit the file, adding a new line *import(sp, rgdal)*. Further reading http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports

Comment: I'd recommend not editing `NAMESPACE` by hand though - `roxygen2` http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/roxygen2/ can make life easier

Comment: So, following this answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597993/does-roxygen2-automatically-write-namespace-directives-for-imports-packages I added an `#' @import rgdal` directive above the function that uses `spTransform` then ran `devtools::document()`. This correctly added the `import(rgdal)` call to `NAMESPACE`